# Has the kilogram changed?

Tags: mass, conventions, definition, si-units, metrology

In late 2018 the kilogram's definition switched from a physical object (the International Prototype Kilogram) to Planck's Constant; a grand move in my opinion.

However, I haven't heard of the consequences resulting from this change. Is 1 kg still 1 kg? Or do we need to now convert pre-2019 masses to the new definition?

Comment: They fixed the value of Planck's constant in such a way that $1 kg$ remains $1 kg$. It's just redefined because having a physical object is inconvenient.

Comment: It's worth noting that the physical artifact is known to have been changing in any case. Those changes were small, but they were annoyingly unpredictable.

Comment: @dmckee True. It was like 50 micrograms lighter or something. Plus kg was the last physical unit not to be based on a constant, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no practical consequences because the changeover was done in a way that ensured no disruption.

For example, before the change, Planck’s constant was a measured value, $6.626070150(81)\times10^{-34}$ Joule-seconds. Now it is a defined value, *exactly* $6.62607015\times10^{-34}$ Joule-seconds. It “changed” to the mean measured value.

This means that any change to the kilogram was at the level of less than one part in a billion. The old kilogram artifact was not stable to that level anyway.

Comment: This might be a separate question, but if the prototype kilogram was not known to one part in a billion, how could Planck's constant be determined to that accuracy? At some point you must calibrate against a physical prototype kilogram surely?

Comment: Good question! Unfortunately, I don’t have an answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the definition of 1kg has changed. This means that what was "1kg" pre-2018 is not what 1kg is in the new definiton. However, this change is **extremely** small, and therefore does not affect our daily lives. Some very precise measurements must be converted, of course, but we are talking about the order of a few micrograms.